# Perform Action Simultaneously when touchdown the UIButton

Tags: iphone

HI...
I have a UIButton with some action when i touch down the button the action performed simultaneously.

Any one know plz answer this..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how your can add an action when you press your button down.

But, for me, your question is not clear...

```
    UIButton * myButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];
[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(doSomeActionMethod) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
```